# How to run opencv C++ eye tracking applicaion.exe file in debug folder VS 2012?

Tags: c++, debugging, opencv, visual-studio-2012, eye-tracking

I created a **eye tracing** program using **OpenCv** and **C++** using **VS2012**.

**When I debug the program it works perfectly.**

but when I **copy debug folder into another place** and run **application.exe** webcam light is ON but program d**oes not work.**

(I have used to use this method for simple applications ago )

(Even camera windows does not open)

Is this happening due to **external libraries** (**OpenCV** and **MySql**) ?

**How can I solve this and run the application.exe in debug folder ?**

Comment: Maybe debug it in the new location.